# django-clever-selects TypeError with method is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

Using django-clever-selects to chain selects but the is_valid() method in the view is causing this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.7.10-0/apps/django/django_projects/freshTest/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.7.10-0/apps/django/django_projects/freshTest/megaForm/views.py" in newForm
  29.         if form.is_valid():
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.7.10-0/apps/django/django_projects/freshTest/clever_selects/forms.py" in is_valid
  191.             activate(self.language_code)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.7.10-0/apps/django/django_projects/freshTest/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py" in activate
  146.     return _trans.activate(language)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.7.10-0/apps/django/django_projects/freshTest/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py" in activate
  217.     if language in _DJANGO_DEPRECATED_LOCALES:

Exception Type: TypeError at /newForm/
Exception Value: unhashable type: 'QueryDict'
```

views.py

```
def newForm(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SimpleChainForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return render(request, 'form1/current_form.html', {
            'form': form,
            'message': (request.POST['cat'],request.POST['columns']),
            # 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
#if GET or other method create blank form
else:
    form=SimpleChainForm()
return render(request, 'form1/current_form.html', {'form': form})
```

The documentation says that django-clever-selects has been 'Tested on Django 1.4.5.', but I need to use 1.8. Is there a work-round/fix for this error? New to django so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tried (but didn't solve) https://github.com/filipefigcorreia/django-clever-selects/commit/4f6da07bb9e880aaaa188297f5866bcbf9c6cab6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this issue, the following worked for me:

https://github.com/filipefigcorreia/django-clever-selects/commit/4f6da07bb9e880aaaa188297f5866bcbf9c6cab6

https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-clever-selects/issues/6

Firstly in clever_selects/forms.py remove these lines

```
def __init__(self, language_code=None, *args, **kwargs):
self.language_code = language_code
```

add in

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
self.language_code = kwargs.get('language_code', None)
```

in my app, forms.py, remove reverse_lazy

```
ajax_url=reverse_lazy('ajax_chained_subtypes') ==> ajax_url='/ajax/chained-subtypes/',
```

generates a bytes string problem, solved with:
clever_selects/forms.py line 97

```
field.choices = field.choices + json.loads(data.content) ==>
field.choices = field.choices + json.loads(data.content.decode("utf-8"))
```